# NSMutable Array and Copying

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, copy

I am looking at someone else's code and they do this. I don't understand why they created a mutable copy of an empty array and then returned a copy of the filled array at the end. How else can you create a Mutable Array and achieve the same result?

```
+(NSArray *)allCats{
    NSMutableArray *catInfo = [@[] mutableCopy];

    NSDictionary *cat1 = @{BREED: @"Siamese Mix", COLOR: @"Grey", NAME: @"Cat1"};
    [catInfo addObject:cat1Dictionary];

    NSDictionary *cat2 = @{BREED: @"Witch Cat", COLOR: @"Black", NAME: @"Cat2"};
    [catInfo addObject:cat2Dictionary];

    NSDictionary *cat3 = @{BREED: @"Tabby", COLOR: @"Grey Striped", NAME: @"Cat3"};
    [catInfo addObject:cat3Dictionary];

    return [catInfo copy];

}
```

Comment: They do the `copy` at the end to return an NSArray (non-mutable) vs an NSMutableArray.  The first statement creating the NSMutableArray is a bit bizarre, though.  A simple `[NSMutableArray array]` would have sufficed, and been clearer and more efficient.

Comment: This data should probably be stored in an external file, anyways. I think the simple answer is that this is just not the best code; there's no need for separate dictionary variables, nor for returning an immutable copy of a locally-created array through `NSArray *`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - The example is, of course, a "toy" one.  But the OP mainly just wants to understand what it's doing and why.

Comment: You're right, I may have taken an overly-broad reading of the question here, @HotLicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `[@[] mutableCopy]` is lazy, but not really bad form. I prefer `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]` or `[NSMutableArray array]`, but it's not terrible. I consider it on the same order as using `[MyObject new]` instead of `[[MyObject alloc] init]`.

The worst part about using `[@[] mutableCopy]` notation is that it allocates an `NSArray`, then allocates an `NSMutableArray`, and then discards the original `NSArray`. It does 2 allocations and a deallocation where one allocation would be sufficient. In the grand scheme of a program, the readability is more important than one extra allocation and deallocation, but purists will crucify you for it.

In the code you posted, the worst thing is that each time `+allCats` is called, it recreates a new copy of all the objects. As that list becomes greater, that will become a massive burden. I would suggest you look into `dispatch_once` and update the code to use it.

Edit:

The code you posted updated to use `dispatch_once` would look like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)allCats
{    
    static NSArray *allCats = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSMutableArray *catInfo = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSDictionary *cat1 = @{BREED: @"Siamese Mix", COLOR: @"Grey", NAME: @"Cat1"};
        [catInfo addObject:cat1Dictionary];

        NSDictionary *cat2 = @{BREED: @"Witch Cat", COLOR: @"Black", NAME: @"Cat2"};
        [catInfo addObject:cat2Dictionary];

        NSDictionary *cat3 = @{BREED: @"Tabby", COLOR: @"Grey Striped", NAME: @"Cat3"};
        [catInfo addObject:cat3Dictionary];

        allCats = [NSArray arrayWithArray:catInfo];
    });
    return allCats;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean about the extra objects. Just to be clear, it affects the system by having extra objects hogging up memory on the heap? Do you also suggest losing the final `return [catInfo copy]`?

Comment: The code you posted does not leak any memory, assuming you're using ARC. It is a matter of cost, in terms of CPU time. Allocating and deallocating objects are relatively expensive tasks. They are cheap compared to disk I/O, but expensive compared to any math, assignment operation, or memory copy.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the 90/10 rule (or 80/20, depending on your religion) applies as much here as anywhere else. 90% of your code runs 10% of the time; 10% of your code runs 90% of the time. If this code is not in a hot spot, the wasteful parts won't really matter.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. My understanding before I saw this code was that it was bad to allocate unnecessary objects, and you confirmed my suspicions about this code. No memory leaks but bad for CPU performance. Good tip about the 90/10!

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs - "Bad to allocate unnecessary objects" is a relative guideline, not a rule.  If taken literally the average iOS program would only allocate about 10% of the objects it does.  Using "unnecessary" objects often makes the code easier to write, easier to understand, more reliable, and, occasionally, faster.  You should never attempt to optimize one aspect of a program at the expense of all others.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to create a mutable instance. Instead you can simply do something like the following:

```
+ (NSArray *)allCats
{    
    return @[@{BREED:@"Siamese Mix", COLOR:@"Grey", NAME:@"Cat1"},
             @{BREED:@"Witch Cat", COLOR:@"Black", NAME:@"Cat2"},
             @{BREED:@"Tabby", COLOR:@"Grey Striped", NAME:@"Cat3"}];
}
```

**Update**

To make the implementation more performant, consider caching the resulting array in a static variable as follows:

```
+ (NSArray *)allCats
{    
    static NSArray *cats;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cats = @[@{BREED:@"Siamese Mix", COLOR:@"Grey", NAME:@"Cat1"},
                 @{BREED:@"Witch Cat", COLOR:@"Black", NAME:@"Cat2"},
                 @{BREED:@"Tabby", COLOR:@"Grey Striped", NAME:@"Cat3"}];
    });

    return cats;
}
```

Comment: This is, of course, possible, but as the list grows to contain more than 3 objects, it becomes unmanageable. I will also point out that each call allocate a completely new copy of the container objects. Besides just being wasteful, it also means that `([MyClass allCats]!=[MyClass allCats])`.

Comment: The OP's question wasn't about performance, but you can simply cache the instance in a static variable to avoid creating the array more than once.

Comment: How does this become unmanageable as the list grows, @Neal, any more than the original procedure?

Comment: Common scenarios would be: "Can you comment out the nth object?" "The Domestic Short Hair should have color set to Light grey." "Add new fields Declawed, Identifier, Disposition, and Age to each cat." Any request of this style would be much simpler on individual objects opposed to a massive structure. Regardless, I would advocate extracting this from the code and putting it into a resource file, such as a Property List.

Comment: Yes, I have on several occasion built large static lists (with "lazy loading") and find it most manageable to break the list init into multiple statements (in some cases actually calling a method to construct each element vs doing it inline).  Control/understanding/management of the list is often of utmost importance.  (And putting the data into some sort of plist is not always ideal, since that can produce too much separation between the data and the code, and it introduces another maintenance step and another way to introduce bugs.)